# On edit gridview , set a value to dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a simple `DropDownList`. A column with the control `DropDownList`.
The DropDownList is containing 2 values : `No/Yes`. I'm not binding something to it.

On `GridView1_rowEditing` I want to set a value to the DropDownList like `SelectedValue = "1";`. So everytime someone is pressing Edit then the value is set to the DropDownList.
I don't want to bind the value from database or something , just set the value to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `GridView1_rowEditing` event search for your DropDownList by its `ID` property using `FindControl` method

```
Int32 rowIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
////////////////////////////////////////////////
GridView1.DataSourceId = "SqlDataSource1"
GridView1.DataBind()
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
DropDownList DropDownList1 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("DropDownList1");
DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "No";
```

**Edit**
Sorry for that, what you need will not be indside `RowEditing` event it will be inside `RowDataBinding` event of your `GridView`. `RowDataBinding` is the place where your row actually get its data and controls

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && 
    (e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit)
   {
       DropDownList DropDownList1= (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");
       DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "No";
   }
}
```

Comment: I think I'm close to what I was searching for , the problem is that that If I press edit I get the error: Object reerence not set to an instance of an object ( MyDDL.SelectedValue = "No"; )

Comment: could you show use your `GridView` code?, it will help us to determine what the problem is.

Comment: this was my actual code http://pastebin.com/sCEmgdNe

Comment: Try to re-bind your `GridView` before finding your `DropDownList`

Comment: how? I don't know what do you mean.

Comment: I used GridVIew1.DataBind() and the same error :-??

Comment: check my edit, I think you should specify the data source again then call `DataBind()` method.

Comment: Same error : object reference not set to an instance of an object ( MyDDL.SelectedValue = "No") everything is fine..but when I press edit..I get that:(( oh ..

Comment: could you show me the code of `RowEditing` event

Answer (score 0):

why you are using this server side event for handling value of dropdown list..???? 
as you said your ddl is by default set to "NO" and its also not databinded...
so remove these liness..only write these two line...

```
GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
GridView1.DataSourceId = "SqlDataSource1"
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: yes I did that , and the error is still there

Comment: in your gridview..Edititemtemplates..you have defined a ddl..simply you had to define 2 list items like <asp:ListItems Text="No" Value="1" seleted="true"> <asp:listItem text="Yes" Value="2"> .....so every time eidt item is clicked the ddl value is by default No..?? So whats the matter left..??

Comment: 1.The code below should set to the dropdown the value yes from the list but when I open the page with the gridview in browser and click edit , it gives me that error 2.I need to know how to set a value from the list everytime the edit button is clicked , and it seems the code below didn't worked , I don't know why . and yes the default value goes to no

Comment: kindly copy here the edit event of your gridview...coz error is in finding your dropdown control i think...!!!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sCEmgdNe take a look at my entire code

Comment: My friend why did not you have defined the list item values in grid view..?? <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="1" Selected="true"> you have only defined the text.!!

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="1" Selected="true"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1" ></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

Comment: 1.I've just transformed the column choose control from textbox into dropdownlist 2.Added 2 items in dropdownlist , but now I changed the lines with what you have said and added another line for text = "Yes" , with selected = false ; and I get error  The 'Text' property of 'asp:ListItem' does not allow child objects.   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Choose") %>'></asp:Label>

Comment: what changes you have made now show me..just add as i mentioned above..do not add label in list item..

Comment: ok now I've changed with what you've said and I get the same error with object refeence etc..

Comment: God , why is not working :( thank you so much for helping, is there any chance to make it work? ty

Comment: i have pasted a sample grid and plz show me or copy here the server side event which your have defined i you grid defination i.e GridView1_RowEditing...??? what is thiss???

Comment: I used your example and I get the same error , this is my row editing :  Int32 rowIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            DropDownList dropdown1 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("DropDownList1");
            dropdown1.SelectedValue = "2";

Comment: try the above one bro.(i have edited the answer)

Comment: remove evry thing from GridView1_RowEditing and only write the above lines which i mentioned in the answer